# Reveal Text from left with CSS or JS animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I want to do a text reveal animation like this:
[video](https://skr.sh/v54HXYtUt6j?a)

```css
.text {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Heebo, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 9px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-block">
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A cupiditate ea eius obcaecati quasi recusandae vitae. Iure perferendis, unde! Aperiam consequatur ipsum iure nisi tenetur? Cupiditate error fugiat libero repellat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can try this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/

Comment: Codepen example: https://codepen.io/dmitrypetrov-dev/pen/vYKQEZg

Answer (score 0):

I used javascript to create solution for that. You simply need to make a loop through all the words you want to append and wrap appending inside `setTimeout` like that:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0];

const words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A cupiditate ea eius obcaecati quasi recusandae vitae. Iure perferendis, unde! Aperiam consequatur ipsum iure nisi tenetur? Cupiditate error fugiat libero repellat.";

words.split(" ").forEach((word, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
       element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word + ' '));
  }, index * 300);
});
```

Also you need to clear your HTML to prevent appending this two times.

Comment: Michał, can you tell me how to change the script so that the text appears by letter?

Comment: Sure, you can just change parameter in split method from `" "` to `""` and remove operation inside `createTextNode` and use only `word` variable there. It will result in splitting your text in every possible place. You can also lower second timeout parameter to make your text appear faster.

Answer (score 0):

With the following custom script, you just need to add the class `typewriter-word` to your element, and the script will do the rest itself.

You can customize the delay between words and the initial delay with the attributes `data-delay` and `data-initial-delay`. Valid values must be at least 0. Any wrong value will be corrected in the script.

The styling of the text in the video you linked can be achieved with some simple CSS.

The script works by...

1. Getting both `data-delay` and `data-initial-delay`, and -if necessary- correcting it
2. Saving the content of the element in an array, and removing said content from the HTML
3. Starting to add content word by word after the `initialDelay`
4. Repeatedly adding the rest of the words after the `delay`
5. After all words are reinserted into the HTML, removing its repeated calls from being unnecessarily called again (`clearInterval(intervalId)`)
6. Repeating steps 1 to 5 for all `.typewriter-word`-elements

The problem with my code is, that you cannot place other elements inside your `.typewriter-word`-element, as you would risk invalidating your HTML, or breaking it completely. This means, you should use this class only on elements not containing other elements, but only (text-)content.

**What's more to add?**
Now, the code is by far not perfect. Other things that could be added are...

- Making use of the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to only start the effect when the element is inside the viewport
- Adding new attributes to make the effect repeat itself for a set amount of times or after a set period of time
- Only start the effect when the element can actually be seen (is inside the DOM)
- Treating nested elements as one word, (and together with previous bullet-point) enabling nested `.typewriter-word`-elements to start their effect once they are inserted, without fiddling around with their `data-initial-delay`-attribute

**Sidenote**
MDN also has an example for a typewriter-effect. However, their approach is a [per character Typewriter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Example_3_Typewriter_simulation). You could try to customize its code to fit your needs.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(".typewriter-word")) {
    // Get both delay and initial delay, both greater than or equal to zero
    let delay = parseInt(el.getAttribute("data-delay"));
    if (isNaN(delay) || delay < 0) delay = 500; // Default value == 500
    let initDelay = parseInt(el.getAttribute("data-initial-delay"));
    if (isNaN(initDelay) || initDelay < 0) initDelay = delay; // Default value == 'delay'
    
    // Save words in array, where words are Strings seperated by " "
    let words = [];
    for (let word of el.innerHTML.split(" "))
      words.push(word);
    
    // Remove content of element
    el.innerHTML = "";
    
    let intervalId; // Variable to save the interval's ID,
                    // to remove interval when finished adding all words
    setTimeout(() => {
      function nextWord() {
        if (words.length <= 0) { // When all words are "printed", clear interval
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          return;
        }
        el.innerHTML += " " + words.shift(); // FIFO via 'Array.shift()' -> No index-usage required!
      }
      
      nextWord(); // Call once -before setInterval()- since setInterval starts firing only after its delay
      intervalId = setInterval(nextWord, delay); // Save interval's ID in variable for removing it when finished
    }, initDelay); // setTimeout(func, initDelay) --> Starting after initial delay
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  background: black
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.1em;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
p:empty {
  padding: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p class="typewriter-word">This text will appear word by word.</p>
<p class="typewriter-word" data-delay="100" data-initial-delay="3500">I will appear faster, but later. Hooray for custom data-attributes!</p>
```

Comment: Oskar, can you tell me how to change the script so that the text appears by letter?

Comment: To quickly change it, you can just replace the string.split-delimiter to "", that would push each letter individually into the array

Comment: But it would probably be better to make a new class `typewriter`, that would save the string itself, and add it back letter by letter, making an array unnecessarily complicated to use. Making it another class would allow you to also use both the word-by-word as well as the letter-by-letter type.